heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones error
I've already searched through forums with the same question, removing doubles is not helping (Edit mode -} M -} by distance). Could someone help, please?
Screenrecording of my problem:
https://youtu.be/WpI5sPW83x4

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external links may be helpful additions to questions they should not remain the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, besides thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be searched for and indexed thus helping future users find it.

Also could you please provide more details about the problem and explain how it differs from the linked duplicate? If it is indeed different from the linked question then we can reopen. Thank you.
